# app.request.attributes.get('_route') is empty when I override 404 error page

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to customize 404 error page so I did:

1) Create app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig

2) I changed is_granted() for {% if app.user and is_granted('...') %} in "layout.html.twig", used by "error404.html.twig"

3) php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug

4) Access in prod enviroment to http:/localhost/app.php and cause 404 error, getting a blank page instead of my custom error page.

I checked my "prod.log" file and I saw a NotFoundHttpException and this Twig error:

request.ERROR: Exception thrown when handling an exception
(Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering
of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "" as
such route does not exist.") in "::layout.html.twig" at line 33.) [] []

It appears that path(app.request.attributes.get('_route')) returns an empty value.

-> How can I get current route and make error page work?<-

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with your current route inside the error page?

Comment: Not in my error page but in my layout, where is my header. It´s to determine the elements of my header. Its elements depends on the current route.

Comment: Do you really need variable header elements if your route is invalid? I'd recommend (more or less) static content for the error page.

Comment: When you're on a 404 page that (usually) means there's no matching route.

Comment: You may find the [WebfactoryExceptionsBundle](https://github.com/webfactory/exceptions-bundle) helpful for testing your pages here.

Answer (score 0):

As Maerlyn says in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876759/app-request-attributes-get-route-is-empty-when-i-override-404-error-page#comment36786833_23876759), it's likely that, if you're on a 404 page, there is no matching route.

However, you can retrieve useful information from the request object which may help you here:

```
{{ app.request.uri }}
```

will return you the full URL of the page the user was trying to access.  And

```
{{ app.request.pathInfo }}
```

will return the path (starting with a slash).

You can find out more about the methods available on the request object by looking at `/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php`.