# Symfony2 app.request.get('_route') is empty when throw new AccessDeniedException

Tags: symfony

I'm working on implementing a ROLE based admin application. I have a custom voter and at some point I'm doing something like:

```
if($role && VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED !== $voteResult) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException('Unauthorized access!');
}
```

and the result is that a custom error403.html.twig template is rendered. 
So far so good.

The error403 template extends the main template in which at some point I'm building a menu using `app.request.get('_route')` for generating the links.

The problem is `app.request.get('_route')` is `null`.

xDebug-ing the issue I've noticed that somehow the `$request->attributes->parameters` array does not contain `_route` or `_route_params` keys.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you perhaps using sub routes?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Symfony uses sub-request for rendering error pages. It doesn't need a router and you have not exatly the same request object as in master request.

Github issue

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5804

Same question on SO

[app.request.attributes.get('_route') is empty when I override 404 error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876759/app-request-attributes-get-route-is-empty-when-i-override-404-error-page?rq=1)

Some theory

https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-journey/sub-request-internals

You can write your own exception listener and modify this behaviour in some way.